# Exchange values in the same vector

Tags: c++, vector

I recently started to see some C ++

But the doubt I have is a bit quick, since I do not find a quick response.
If I have a vector in C ++ how can I interchange the values of it?

in Python:

```
x = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
x[0], x[1] = x[1], x[0]

Output: ["b", "a", "c", "d"]
```

in C++:

```
std::vector <char> x {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
char n = x.at(0);
x[0] = x[1];
x[1] = n;
```

Just out of curiosity is there a different way in C ++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
std::swap(x[0],x[1]);
```

This is C++11 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap):

```
std::swap(x[0], x[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use swap or temporary variable or xor:

```
char tmp = x[0];
x[0] = x[1];
x[1] = tmp;
```

or:

```
x[0] ^= x[1];
x[1] ^= x[0];
x[0] ^= x[1];
```

or swap:

```
swap(x[0], x[1]);
```